Ошибка с установкой visual Studio. Не удалось установить Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community,Shared.Msi
В общем и целом, после обновления визуал студио возникает такая ошибка. После прошлой обновы снес винду и помогло, сейчас уже не хочу этим заниматься.
Прочитал, что нужно поменять разрешения в ключе реестра, но при попытке открытия файлов редактор регистра лагает. Через консоль тоже не получается что-то. Помогите пожалуйста, уже сил моих нет....



Лог смотрите и изучайте там конкретную ошибку. "Не удалось установить" - это просто "ОШИБКА", которая ничего не говорит... А так, есть вон у Microsoft официальные каналы связи, официальная поддержка, стоит написать им.

Текстовую информацию нужно вставлять текстом, а не картинками.
